# Icons before buttons in LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-icons

How can I place icons in front of buttons on LinearLayout using ImageView? I attach the Android activity xml code and a screenshot of the app's appearance for clarity. Please help me! I would be grateful for any information from knowledgeable people

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#00a89b">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="BUTTON1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="BUTTON2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="BUTTON3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="BUTTON4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="BUTTON5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="BUTTON6" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

[The appearance of the app] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcwvp.png

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but if you want to use `LinearLayout` you can do this:

Wrap each `<Button>` inside another `<LinearLayout>` with `orientation="horizontal"` and put an `<ImageView>` also inside each `<LinearLayout>` before the `<Button>`. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width=..."
            android:layout_height="..."
            .../>
            
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="BUTTON1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
```

You might want to add some margins or padding in between the `ImageView` and the `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `android:background`, you can use `android:drawableLeft`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#00a89b">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="BUTTON1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="BUTTON2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="BUTTON3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="BUTTON4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="BUTTON5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="BUTTON6" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show the icon outside the button so `drawableLeft` will not be a suitable option to achieve that. Your desired design can be done with **ConstraintLayout** effectively but as you asked to do it by **LinearLayout**. So here is the complete solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00a89b"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon">

            </ImageView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:background="@drawable/green_border"
                android:text="BUTTON1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon">

            </ImageView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:background="@drawable/green_border"
                android:text="BUTTON2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon">

            </ImageView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:background="@drawable/green_border"
                android:text="BUTTON3"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon">

            </ImageView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:background="@drawable/green_border"
                android:text="BUTTON4"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon">

            </ImageView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:background="@drawable/green_border"
                android:text="BUTTON5"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon">

            </ImageView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:background="@drawable/green_border"
                android:text="BUTTON6"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```